# How to avoid the render method to get called each time a view is displayed when using TabBarIOS

Tags: react-native

I'm building an app which views are inside tabs. 
Some of the views render lists from data fetched by a call to an api.
I noticed that the render method is callled every time I hit the tab. 
This causes the render method to re-render the list, so there is a delay and this not user friendly at all, as it takes some time.

How can I render the views only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) method for each react component
you don't want to re-render each time it's props or state changed

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!